# How to prevent stacked activity from showing when app is re-launched?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an annoying issue with the activity stack that I haven't found a solution for.

Basically I have an activity that acts as a "starter" activity (the main activity in my manifest, this is started from the launcher etc). It is translucent, set using:

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"

What it does is check the Intent that is fed to it. If the intent data is empty, it starts a new activity which is the main activity for the app.

If the intent data contains certain commands the starter activity should perform certain tasks and then exit, not even starting the main activity. So this should happen without any UI (except for a popup message when done).

My problem is that if the main activity has been started, if the user uses the home button to leave it, the next time the starter activity is started with a command, the main activity also shows up briefly.

I'm assuming this is because of the activity stack since I'm not restarting the main activity from the starter activity in this case.

I've tried various solutions to no avail. I can't use finish() in the main activity in onPause or onStop since that also exits the activity if the user for example enters the settings activity and that is not wanted behavior. I also tried variations of re-launching the starter activity with

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

but that doesn't seem to work either.

The thing that is weird is that when this unwanted behavior happens, onCreate/onResume/onStart is *not* called on the main activity. Still it shows! I'm guessing this is because it is stacked and since the startup activity is translucent, the main activity is shown through it.

Comment: For now I've resorted to keeping track of when the user leaves main. If it leaves it to start another activity within the app, I do nothing. If it leaves it for some other reason (e.g. home press) I finish the activity.

This works but if someone has a better suggestion, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the `android:noHistory` attribute on your activity within your manifest:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:noHistory="true">
    ...
</activity>
```

This will set the activity to be removed from the activity stack when it starts the next activity. The user will not be able to return to an activity that has `android:noHistory="true"`.

See:

- [Activity Attribute: `android:noHistory`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist)

Comment: Thanks but that will cause the same problems as when using finish(). THe main activity can spawn a preferences activity as well as another activity and the user should be able to get back to the main activity when leaving those activities...

Comment: I'm a bit unsure of your desired activity flow. Is it 'starter'->'main'->'some_other_one'? And occasionally 'some_other_one' will trigger main to show again?

Comment: It's starter->main->(sometimes)some_other_one, where some_other_one could be a preferences activity. And from some_other_one it should be possible to go back to main. 

It can also be just 'starter' depending on the intent and in that's when I get the problem with 'main' also showing.

For now I've resorted to keeping track of when the user leaves main. If it leaves it to start another activity within the app, I do nothing. If it leaves it for some other reason (e.g. home press) I finish the activity.

Comment: Could you pass some data into the intent to identify what activity triggered the main activity to show and react appropriately? You could also set the visibility of mains root layout to `gone` or `invisible` to hide it. It's a bit of a hack but would achieve a similar effect.

Comment: THanks for the suggestion but I couldn't get it working. Tried using getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); in the onResume of the main activity and getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().setVisibility(View.GONE); in onStop but it would still flash show in the same way as described above. Not sure why...